# How do I create a Cocoa (Obj-C) Dynamic Library for OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, mach-o

So basically I want to create a Dynamic Library in OS X that is built utilizing Cocoa (In Obj-C, not C or C++).  My question is - how do I do this?

Ultimately I want the library to be loaded by another application (which I know how to do).  I just don't know how to create a module utilizing Objective-C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating your own framework instead of a library.
[Guide 1](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html)
[Guide 2](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/09/04/cocoa-tutorial-creating-your-very-own-framework/)

If you're bent on making a Dynamic Lib then check this [Guide 3](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html) out.  I recommend against dynamic libs because I believe they're banned/frowned upon by Apple when approving iPhone apps.

Frameworks will give you the same functionality, plus a ton more options for resources, headerfiles, etc.  Plus, you'll be following Apple's design patterns which means your code will run better.

Comment: Do you have a source for dylibs being banned but frameworks being allowed on iOS? That would be surprising, since a framework is essentially just a dylib wrapped in a thick directory structure.

Comment: Agreed. But "Apple's design patterns" don't make any code run better. They keep it clean, that's all.

Comment: lol @Chuck, DURR - no, of course not.  It's static libs that Apple's not happy about, sorry.  True, @Max, clean is 'better' for some. :D